# Django: Dynamically create a Q() with and

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-q

I have a use case where there's a csv that's imported and I need to check to make sure that all entries of a particular column correspond to the same object.

For instance, say:

```
l = ['test1', 'test2']
```

I need something like:

```
Model.objects.filter(Q(id='test1') and Q(id='test2')
```

I won't know how many elements are in l, so how can I construct a query that will allow me to do this:

I've tried:

```
h = Q()
for i in l:
   h &= Q(id=i)
```

but that doesn't work

Any help is appreciated

Update:

This also doesn't work

```
Models.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, l))
```

I think the operator.and_ is the & operator, and that's why it doesn't work.  Can this even be done!!

Answer (score 0):

AND is the default operation for `filter()`.

```
Models.objects.filter(*l)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe that?

```
if l: # 'l' is a bad variable name
  query = Models.objects  # this returns all objects!
  for item in l:
    query = query.filter(id=item) # each filter adds a 'and'
  return query.exits()
else:
  return False  # If no values, does it return False?
```

do you really ask by id field? isn't it unique for each Models instance?